# How to access a function or variable from the parent iframe in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

i have two iframes one is parent another one is child and on button click in child iframe i need to access the function or variable from the parent iframe.

Parent iframe:

```
<iframe id="parentiframe" scrolling="true" src="#"></iframe>
```

parent function:

```
function iframe1function() { //$('#SUBFORAPPRL span').click();

    $("[id='field_Update Status'] span").click();
    $('.quote-title-span8').text('Approved');
    $('#approval_act_btn').hide();
  
}
```

Child iframe:

```
<iframe src="../../quotation/Approvals.aspx" loading="lazy" height="600" width="100%" id="childIframe" title="Approve Iframe"></iframe>
```

child button:

```
<button type="button" id="act_btn" class="art10" onclick="iframe1function()">button</button>
```

Comment: would you believe it's `parent.iframe1function()`?

Comment: Do you want to call function from parent page, or the function is in another iframe?

Comment: from another iframe.